# Android project is compiled with the old data

Tags: java, android, project

I am kind of new in Android and today I cannot get rid of an activity.
I've deleted the intent that riches the activity, and the Activity class itself, but when I run the application the old deleted activity is still running, I've restarted eclipse, the testing phone and everything I could restart.
Please give me an Idea what could that be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete gen folder and rebuild your project. Do that by going to `Project -> Clean`.

Comment: what do you mean by rebuild?

Comment: first delete gen folder, and rebuild in Project Clean.